# How to style multiple elements to fix them to 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
...
<div>
    <label>Identification:</label>
    <input type="text" name="identification" value="" maxlength="20">
    <strong class="characters">20</strong>
    <p class="description">
        <span class="icon_description"></span>Item description
    </p>
</div>
...
```

now it looks  like this image
[image]

I need improve it to 100% of parent element.
So `label` could be fixed to specific width and rest of elements to rest of width space. 
How to do it by css3 for cross browsers please?

Comment: What do you mean **how to style it cross browsers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I corrected some code. Following code works in all browsers.

```
<!Doctype>
<html>

<body>
<div style="width:500px;margin-top:40px;">
<label style="width:86px;float:left;">Identification:</label>

    <div  style="width:404px;float:right;margin-left:10px;">
    <input type="text" name="identification" value="" maxlength="20"    style="width:45%;">
    <strong class="characters"  style="width:10%;">40</strong>
    <h4 style="width:45%;float:right;margin-top:0px;">Item description</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```